# Possible to add events to d3 dispatcher?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have created a new d3-dispatcher in d3 v4

```
var dispatch = d3.dispatch("start")
```

Is it possible to add another event at a later time? I want to add an "end" event like :

```
dispatch.addEvent("end")
```

Answer (score -2):

No, you can't.

Basically, you should use dispatch like this:

```
var dispatch = d3.dispatch("start","end")   
dispatch.on("start", function(d) {
  // do things on start first
  dispatch.on("end", function(d) {
    // do things later on end
  });   
});
```

You could try to use `setTimeout()` too (not tested):

```
setTimeout(function() {
   dispatch.on("end", function(d) {
     // do things later on end
   });
}, 2000);
```